# Jenkins is spawning a lot of daemon processes and server crashes

Tags: jenkins, centos, centos7

I've recently installed Jenkins on a cheap VM on Azure. The specs are very low, since I use this server for testing the setup: 1vCPU & 1GB RAM. There will usually only be 1 build at the same time, with a max. of 3, in very rare occassions.

During the build process from Jenkins quite frequently my server would crash completely and stay so for +- 10 - 15 minutes until being able to be used again.

I checked the processes on the server and this is the result:
[image: running processes]

The full line is like this:

```
/etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

It is the same for every single one of those daemons, not a single parameter is different.

Is this normal behavior, and is this the reason why my server is crashing? Or are my specs just too low for Jenkins to run on to?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
My jenkins.log file looks pretty normal except for one NullPointerException that keeps coming back up:

```
    2020-01-08 12:43:17.702+0000 [id=148]   WARNING h.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression#evaluate: Caught exception evaluating: h.filterDescriptors(it,attrs.descriptors) in /configure. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class hudson.model.Hudson' in thread 'Handling GET /configure from 85.154.65.124 : qtp2085857771-148 Jenkins/configure.jelly GlobalLibraries/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class hudson.model.Hudson' in thread 'Handling GET /configure from 85.154.65.124 : qtp2085857771-148 Jenkins/configure.jelly GlobalLibraries/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
            at hudson.model.DescriptorVisibilityFilter.apply(DescriptorVisibilityFilter.java:73)
            ...
```

Comment: Definitely not normal. Can you see if the entire line is the same (ie:no different parms) and post one entire line (as text) if so /& diffs if there are. Did you examine /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log? How are you launching Jenkins (wrapper - post)? Size wise, did you review [installing](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/) and [HW Reps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/)

Comment: The lines are all exactly the same, they look like this:
/etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 

I am not using Docker, i've done a normal, manual, install on my CentOS7 server.

I've tried looking in those jenkins.log files, but i have no idea where to look for and what looks off and what looks right...

Comment: @Dennis did you ever solve this ? Im seeing the exact same thing

Comment: Threads on Linux are implemented as processes, that's why you see many processes with the exact same command. If you press F2 and check "Hide userland threads", I'll not see those in `htop`. Many threads are expected in Jenkins/JVM in general, you might be able to configure those using `handlerCountMax` etc.